# Tkinter create image function error: pyimage1 does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was writing code for a minesweeper program but I keep on getting an error message that states that "pyimage1" does not exist. The error, I suspect originates from "def frame" and or "class control". I have seen others post similar questions yet to no avail. The images themselves block.png and flag.png are not corrupt. Previous tests show that it worked but started to fail when I integrated multiple windows(one with the visuals and the other with the control buttons)

```
C:\Users\akiva\PycharmProjects\helloOpencv\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/akiva/PycharmProjects/helloOpencv/operation.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akiva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\akiva\PycharmProjects\helloOpencv\mine_sweeper.py", line 72, in frame
    self.canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=self.block_pic)
  File "C:\Users\akiva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2489, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\akiva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from time import sleep


class ResizingCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()

    def on_resize(self,event):
        # determine the ratio of old width/height to new width/height
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        # resize the canvas
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        # rescale all the objects tagged with the "all" tag
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)


class Minesweeper(Tk):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        fr = Frame(self)
        fr.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.canvas = ResizingCanvas(fr, width=940, height=920, bg="black", highlightthickness=0)
        self.count = 0
        self.start = 0
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Control(self, self.newWindow)
        self.title("MineSweeper")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        x1 = 20
        y1 = 20
        x2 = 80
        y2 = 80
        self.block_pic = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/akiva/OneDrive/Desktop/akiva/Python Files/block.PNG')
        self.flag_pic = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/akiva/OneDrive/Desktop/akiva/Python Files/flag.PNG')
        for k in range(14):
            for i in range(15):
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='white')
                x1 += 60
                x2 += 60
            x1 = 20
            x2 = 80
            y1 += 60
            y2 += 60

    def shift_image(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            Tk.canvas.itemconfig(self.block_pic, image=self.flag_pic)

    def end(self):
        self.start = 0
        del self.block_pic
        print("Game has ended")
        self.after(2000, quit())

    def frame(self):
        self.start += 1
        if self.start == 1:
            x1 = 50
            y1 = 50
            for i in range(14):
                for k in range(15):
                    self.canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=self.block_pic)
                    x1 += 60
                x1 = 50
                y1 += 60
            self.canvas.pack()
        else:
            print("Game has already started")


class Control(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        start_button = Button(self.frame, text="Start Game", command=parent.frame,)
        stop_button = Button(self.frame, text="End Game", command=parent.end)
        start_button.pack()
        stop_button.pack()
        self.quitButton = Button(self.frame, text='Quit', width=25, command=self.close_windows)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```

Comment: Why are you asking same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500010/im-losing-my-mind-whats-wrong-pythontkinter) twice?

Comment: I actually think you need to open the image first with `self.block_pic = Image.open('path.png')` then pass that on to your `self.pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.block_pic)`